# PrimeFaces frozen after SocketTimeoutException (and how to unfreeze)?

Tags: ajax, primefaces, timeout

I have becommen the `SocketTimeoutException`, which is quite hard to replicate now, but it is not the most important here. What is troubling me is the reaction of the **PrimeFaces** UI on such happening. The UI got frozen, so no AJAX clicks were processed (one could click what one will but nothing happened).

I don't know the PrimeFaces internals well, but with my experience with AJAX apps, it could happen where we have the AJAX queue and the job is not released after unexpected error happens. Is it the case here?

And how to prevent such behaviour? Or if prevention is not possible, is it possible to "restart" the AJAX engine of PrimeFaces in Javascript? As the last resort I could provide the special button to "reset" the AJAX state without "refreshing" (which should be rather called destroy-all-my-changes) the site?

Comment: Resetting the page (F5) is not an option, I suppose. I had a lot of problem with view-scoped beans expiring, one good thing to do is to rely the least possible in AJAX. Also, the PF JS internals are a cat's cradle, and undocumented to boot. Kind of a black box. For restarting the AJAX engine, the Java POJOs on server-side would still have to be alive, and I do not think that they will be after this `SocketTimeoutException`

Comment: For some sensitive pages, I usuallly bind all controls to AJAX calls, so the server-side data model is always up-to-date with the browser view. Network overhead? yes, but someone has to pay the price. Then the managedBean for the page can restore the fields if page is refreshed.

Comment: In this case I think it was timeout with single request, but it was definitely shorter than the view timeout, so some server call has fallen, but the view was alive. the problem was there were no requests sent from client to server anymore.